# How do I use an Android constant value of FILL_PARENT from java

Tags: android, constants

**BACKGROUND:**  The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT) states:

> **Constants**
> public static final int FILL_PARENT
>
> Special value for the height or width requested by a View. FILL_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any. This value is deprecated starting in API Level 8 and replaced by MATCH_PARENT.
>
> Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)

**QUESTION:**
I'm sure it is not expected for me to actually define this value, but it is not clear how to use it.

For example: I want to say something like

LayoutParams slp = new LayoutParams(android.R.FILL_PARENT,android.R.FILL_PARENT);

But I know that is not right.

How do I access this constant from **java**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constant is used to specify a layout width or height so in xml
you would do this

```
android:layout_width="FILL_PARENT"
```

and in code do

```
new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```